# What does too many values to unpack in python mran?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop, debugging

I am a beginner in python i wants to print a dictionary of the code below in the form of English:95 or English, 95 i used a for loop but this isn't working.

```
grade8_midterm = {'English': 95, 'Maths': 99, 'German': 86, 'History':96, 'Science': 91}
grade8_final = {'English': 92, 'Maths': 100, 'German': 89, 'History':92, 'Science': 99}
for x, y in grade8_midterm.keys(), grade8_midterm.values():
    print (x, y)
```

This is the output i am getting:

```
    for x, y in grade8_midterm.keys(), grade8_midterm.values():
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: `for x, y in zip(grade8_midterm.keys(), grade8_midterm.values()):`

Comment: ```for x, y in grade8_midterm.items():```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
for x, y in grade8_midterm.items():
    print (x, y)
```

`dict.items()` will return a list of tuples of key value pairs in the dictionary

Example,

```
d = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
(print(d.items())
```

The output is

```
dict_items([('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)])
```

Comment: nitpick: `dict.items()` returns a *set-like* collection. It is not a *sequence*, to say nothing of being an actual *list* e.g. it is not indexable or sliceable.

Comment: True. I was trying to explain in layman's terms since OP said they're a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

You've gotten the information of what you should do, but here's what the error is:

```
grade8_midterm.keys(), grade8_midterm.values()
```

is a *tuple literal*, the "tuple operator" in Python is the comma and the parens are optional (if unambiguous). So what you're writing here is

```py
for x, y in (a, b):
   ...
```

which is equivalent to

```py
for x, y in [a, b]:
   ...
```

which you might be more familiar with.

This means you're really executing

```py
x, y = grade8_midterm.keys()
...
x, y = grade8_midterm.values()
...
```

which means Python expects the value (right-hand side of the assignment) to have 2 items in order to assign them to the 2 targets (left-hand side of the assignment).

Since your dict has 5 entries, it has 5 keys, so the first assignment is a mismatch and triggers the error you see: Python expected to receive 2 values to unpack (matching the LHS) and received a different number thereof.